# How does the Grammarly chrome extension work

Tags: google-chrome-extension, grammarly

I was wondering how the Grammarly extension is able to underline the words in almost any editor (tinyMCE, CKE etc). I thought they are doing that via CSS but it's not.

I am trying to implement something similar and am very thankful for any advice.

Best

Comment: I've built similar functionality and at scale it's nuts how challenging it is to do right. I have no idea how Grammarly has done it so well. Although it's an interesting discussion, this question belongs on Upwork, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: Are there any open-source examples of something similar? The code needed to reverse engineer the canvas-based rendering is crazy